# ZARR: Inefficiency in Selecting Data Based on Bounding Box Coordinates with TIME Dimensions Only dataset

Tags: dask, geopandas, python-xarray, zarr, data-cube

I have the following dataset which is a trajectory type dataset.
LATITUDE and LONGITUDE are defined as coordinates in xarray **BUT** they **aren't** dimensions! All of the issues I've came across on stackoverflow and forums have LATITUDE and LONGITUDE as dimension.

Here's a brief overview of the dataset.

```
Dimensions:
TIME: 120385119

Coordinates:
DEPTH (TIME) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(10000,), meta=np.ndarray>
LATITUDE (TIME) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(10000,), meta=np.ndarray>
LONGITUDE (TIME) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(10000,), meta=np.ndarray>
TIME (TIME) datetime64[ns]
2008-11-25T00:54:26.443568128 .....

Data variables: (61)

Indexes: (1)

Attributes: (43)
```

My issue is that this dataset, currently stored on S3 as a ZARR dataset, is horrendously slow at selecting data based on a geographical bounding box. Selecting based on TIME is fine though since it's a dimension.

In a perfect world, I'd like to achieve this:

```py
%%time
import xarray as xr
import fsspec

# remote zarr dataset
url = 's3://imos-data-lab-optimised/zarr/target.zarr'
ds = xr.open_zarr(fsspec.get_mapper(url, anon=True), consolidated=True,  chunks={'TIME': 10000}) # maybe important to load the ds with chunks not to kill the amount of ram

subset = ds[['PSAL', 'TEMP', 'DEPTH']]
subset = subset.where((ds.LONGITUDE>=151) & (ds.LONGITUDE<=152) & (ds.LATITUDE>=-34) & (ds.LATITUDE<=-33), drop=True)
subset
```

Unfortunately, the current process is time-consuming since it involves downloading all the chunks for LATITUDE and LONGITUDE to locate the required data, which is counterproductive. I aim to accomplish a more efficient approach similar to setting an index on a column, as seen in PostgreSQL, for instance.

I've tried several approaches, including indexing, using a pandas multiindex, and attempting regridding (though it seems impractical due to the array's size). However, I find myself going in circles, and I can't believe no one else has encountered this issue.

I'm open to suggestions in possibly re-writting this zarr dataset, considering that the dataset is not static and grows with new trajectories and timestamp overtime.

Comment: Hi, I would recommand posting your question to https://discourse.pangeo.io/.